# If a cell is red, it generates a message box, but if it isn't it calls to run another macro

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox

I am trying to build a workbook that is set to conditionally format if a certain range of cells has a 0 value, the range is dynamic based on what data is entered into the sheet on any given day. So, I thought I could conditionally format the cells to turn red in the event a cell has 0. I did this by doing this macro

```
Sub ColorTACsErrorCheck()
'
' Checks for any TACs Errors with 0 value
'

'
    Sheets("TACS Data").Select
    Range("N2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = vbRed
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = vbRed
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

It works perfectly, and works with dynamic ranges.

I tried using the below code to have it generate a message if one of the cells is red, which it does, but I want it to not run the actual macros I have for the rest of the workbook IF it has a red cell. However, it seems to call the macro regardless.

```
Sub Message()
'
' Message
'

'
    Sheets("TACS Data").Select
    Dim oneCell As Range, newNote As String
    For Each oneCell In Sheets("TACS Data").Range("N3:N100")
    With oneCell
        If oneCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            MsgBox "A carrier did not clock to the street. Please correct this error and rerun Employee Moves report in TACs."
            If newNote = "False" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else: Call Run
        End If
        End If
    End With
    Next oneCell
End Sub
```

I'm trying to make the workbook as user friendly as possible so that people who don't know Excel only have to hit "Run" and if there are no errors, it runs the entire report to get results, but if there is an error it simply tells them to try again basically.

Is this possible? Or should I just have a "check for errors" button that they have to hit before the "run report" button?

Comment: Could you clarify this: "`using the below code to have it generate a message if one of the cells is red, which it does, but I want it to not run the actual macros I have for the rest of the workbook IF it has a red cell.'"

Comment: @TinMan So the report will only truly run properly if there are no what we call "clock ring errors." If there are clock ring errors,  the report will run, but the data will be skewed. So, instead of others running the report and potentially getting incorrect data, I want it to stop it at the beginning and have them fix the errors. However, if there are no errors, the report can run and the macro I have written in VBA will work just fine, so basically, if there is an error I don't want the report to run, if there isn't an error, I want the report to run. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Shouldn't `Call Run` be after `Next oneCell`? Also, this `If newNote = "False" Then` does nothing i.e. it's never true!? After the message box use `Exit Sub: End If: End With: Next oneCell: Call Run`. The `Call` keyword is considered deprecated and you should rename `Run` to something more meaningful e.g. Just use `RunProgram`. Think about abandoning the Conditional Formatting idea by using `If Application.CountIf(Worksheets("TACS Data").Range("N3:N100"), 0) > 0 Then Exit Sub` or even better `If IsNumeric(Application.Match(0, Worksheets("TACS Data").Range("N3:N100"), 0)) Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: `newNote ` is never assigned a value.

Comment: @VBasic2008 this worked perfectly! Thank you! I knew I was making it more complicated than it had to be but couldn't think my way out of it!

Comment: @VBasic2008 Okay now I have a new question. I'm trying to get Excel to pop up a message if there is a particular anomaly that could happen. The anomaly would case data to be in a random cell in Colum C, but no data in Column A or B. Can I write something in VBA to use IsEmpty for adjacent cells when the data is dynamic, something the cell in question could be C2 or sometimes C18 etc. Does that make sense?